# How can I run VLC in a href (beamer)

Tags: beamer, hyperref

I have a beamer presentation and I want to launch a video clicking on a picture

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
...
\href{run:C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe getR.avi}{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{Rlogo.jpg}}
```

When I do this I see the Rlogo.jpg but when I click on it I get "Cannot open file"
How can I do this ?

**EDIT:**
Alex solution gave an error

Here is the code

```
\frame{ \frametitle{une petite vidéo ;-)}
\includemedia[
  addresource=getR.mp4,
  windowed=1024x768,
  flashvars={
    source=getR.mp4
   &autoPlay=true
   &scaleMode=letterbox
  }
]{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{RStudio.jpg}}{VPlayer.swf}
}
```

---

Here is the slide

[image: the slide]

---

Here is the result when I click

[image: the error when I click]

---

Here is my package version

[image: what miktex tells me about media9]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Did you try `/` instead of ``\\`` in the path?

Comment: Do you know that you can also read videos directly in the pdf with the `media9` package?

Comment: @egreg: yes I tried, I also created a .bat file and try to put `run:mybat.bat` but It failed too :(

Comment: @Corentin: salut, I know about `media9` but I would like to have the video on full screen and those are `.avi` I think `media9` embed videos and only take `.swp`. If I can get the same (a picture I click on that launch vlc or whatever to se the video in full screen I am happy to swap)

Comment: There is a `windowed=<width in pix>x<height in pix>` option with `\includemedia` from `media9` which allows you to play the video in a detached window (requires Media9 version .ge. 0.18, 2012/12/21). Media9 takes FLV and H.264 videos, which can easily be encoded using FFmpeg or an online service.

Comment: I'd guess the problem is caused by spaces in the path to `vlc.exe`. Try putting double quotes `"` around `C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc.exe`; maybe you'll have to escape them by `\`. (Sorry, I can't test this, because I don't use Windows.)

Comment: @AlexG: thanks, I am using windows 7, texnic center and Miktec (last versions). How can I check that I have the right media9 version and would you mind showing me an example (one liner) of how to include the video fullscreen ?

Comment: Exact fullscreen can only be achieved manually through right-click on the video and selecting *Full Screen Multimedia*. Automatic fullscreen is not possible for security reasons imposed by Adobe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This doesn't exactly answer your question because VLC is not used.

With `media9`, a video can be configured to play in a floating window of arbitrary size rather than in an embedded fashion. The video must be either in the FLV or in the H.264 format, though. But this can be easily done using an online service or FFmpeg on the command line:

```
ffmpeg -i getR.avi -vcodec libx264 getR.mp4
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i getR.avi getR.flv
```

The video would be embedded as

```
\includemedia[
  addresource=getR.mp4,
  windowed=1024x768,
  flashvars={
    source=getR.mp4
   &autoPlay=true
   &scaleMode=letterbox
  }
]{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{Rlogo.jpg}}{VPlayer.swf}
```

You may want to experiment with the window size (option `windowed`).

The `scaleMode=letterbox` FlashVar ensures that the video is resized correctly, in case its aspect ratio doesn't match the one of the playback window.

Alternatively, `scaleMode=none` suppresses rescaling of the video and it will be shown at its natural size. No pixel interpolations will take place which otherwise might be the source of undesired artefacts.

Comment: just an additional question, what is VPlayer.swf for at the end how is it generated ?

Comment: @statquant I have just uploaded a new media9 version to CTAN. From now on, the floating player window will show up centred on the screen. (With MiKTeX it may take up to one week to be available, with TeXLive ... overnight.)

Comment: @statquant: `VPlayer.swf` is the video player (a Flash app) that ships with media9 and which is configured via FlashVars (option `flashvars`). You don't need to copy it into your working directory. `VPlayer.swf` doesn't have control buttons, but you can pause/resume playback via mouse button down/up and via the space bar on the keyboard; seeking with arrow keys <--, -->.

Comment: @statquant: You're welcome. Manual install is always possible (as explained in the documentation), but I think it is not worth it. At present, the floating video window is positioned top left on the screen. So it makes no difference if it is big enough. Only make sure you did a package update with the MiKTeX package manager recently.

Comment: OUch not working I updated my post

Comment: @statquant: Maybe something is wrong with `getR.mp4`. Try `random.mp4` from the media9 package installation to check that everything else is ok.

Comment: Damn it works with random, It means that I have problems with my videos ? They are playing fine on VLC and media player though... I am a bit puzzled :(

Comment: @statquant wrong codec i would say. Try flv instead.

Comment: Ok indeed flv works fine, but the quality looks much lower, even if I set it to max. (from a 30Mo .avi I go to 1Mo flv), I can look for a better converter I guess but it's too bad

Comment: Ok I finally found a good compromize, Camstudio with highest quality write .avi that I convert with Media Converter to flv.

Last question Alex, when the video is on, can I pause ? and can I quit and go directly back to the pdf, at the moment I click on the X at top right and click back to the presentation but it's not very responsive

Comment: @statquant: I'd close or minimize the video by right-click on the video and chose from the context menu. (It is easier than targetting the X).

Comment: Ok, but then It might be easier to place the video in small just above the picture as I have to use the mouse anyway, can I specify where the video is gonna appear on the screen ?

Comment: @statquant: not yet. I might add an optional `@<position>` to the window dimensions, where `<position>` would be something like `center`, `topleft`, `bottomcenter`, etc. Exact pixel positions would be futile as you never know the screen resolution and the page zoom beforehand.

Answer (score 9):

Over Windows, you can just write the path of the video file

```
\href{run:C:\\Users\\yourname\\yourfolder\\getR.avi}{\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{Rlogo.jpg}}
```

without any other packages like `\usepackage{multimedia}` or others.
The video will run using the standard multimedia program of your operative system Windows.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: The text after `run:` is used in a file specification (see PDF specification). AFAIK the first argument of `\href` should read `run:/c/Users/yourname/yourfolder/getR.avi`. (But it also might depend on the PDF viewer.)